# objective-c app update and core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

One thing bothers me, I am developing iOS app. Firstly when hasPerformedFirstLaunch I load core data, it works good. But later, when I'll update my app. I would like to change core data. How can I do this or How you do this? It is an app where a lot of data that will accrue updates.

My first launch

```
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasPerformedFirstLaunch"]) {
    [self initialCoreData];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasPerformedFirstLaunch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data has the ability to migrate models from old versions to newer ones automatically, albeit with a few limitations. There's [lots of documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) and there are some decent tutorials around if you search for "lightweight migration."

Answer (score 2):

Let's define what are you meaning by "saying change core data".

- Are you talking about changing the model schema ?
- or just update your bundled db?

In the first case you should follow the migration procedure of core data, there are a lot of information on how to do it. Basically you have 2 options, the light migration or the heavier one.
In the second case is just easy as change a bundled file, but if you also changed the model scheme you are going to encounter a crash pretty soon.